# Can we execute steps conditionally in a JMeter script?

Tags: automation, testing, jmeter, error-handling

I have recorded a sequence of steps to be executed for testing my web application, in a JMeter .jmx script. (The recording tool used was BadBoy).

It is possible that one of the steps might return an error response in the HTTP response content. In this case, I need the script to stop execution of that thread.
However, since the error page is customized, JMeter does not recognize this as an error and proceeds to the next steps.

Is there any way to check for certain keywords, for example, and decide if the response is an error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assertions.

http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter/usermanual/test_plan.html#assertions

Answer (score 0):

You can use "Response Assertion" in combination with reg-ex in order to extract the pattern that identifies whether the request is successful or not.
Then you can use "Result Status Action Handler" post-processor to tell JMeter how to continue.